# Finding the axes of an ellipse using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

From Demidovich:

> Find the axes of the ellipse $5x^2 + 8xy + 5y^2 = 9$ using Lagrange multipliers.

I've tried to separate into two equations, $g(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)$, to apply

$$\nabla f(x,y) = -\lambda \nabla g(x,y)$$

What I got was that:

$$f(x,y) = 5x^2 + 5y^2 - 1 = 0$$ and $$g(x,y) = 8xy - 8 = 0$$

Then I applied the formula:

$$\nabla f(x,y) = (10x, 10y) \quad \nabla g(x,y) = (8y, 8x)$$

$$\begin{cases} 10x = -\lambda 8y \\
                       10y = - \lambda 8x \end{cases}$$

And what I got was that $ x = \pm 1 = y$, which gives me that $2a = 2b = 2$ but in the Demidovich it says that the solution is $2a = 6$ and $2b = 2$ and to use the fact that the distance from any point (x,y) of the ellipse from its centre is equal to $x^2 + y^2$. I've tried to considere $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $g(x,y) = 5x^2 + 8xy + 5y^2 = 9$ but I can't get the right result.

Comment: The constraint used here is $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is some constant. The gradient of the ellipse function is $(10x+8y, 8x+10y).$   When is that vector field parallel to $(2x,2y) \; ? \;$

Comment: Or, since they have given a constant value for the ellipse, we could say to find the extrema of $x^2 + y^2$ on that ellipse. Same calculation, when is $(5x+4y, 4x+5y) $ a multiple (by some $\lambda$) of $(x,y)$

Comment: I've tried this and finally got the right result, just as user stated in his comment, anyways, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try with the function
$F(x,y,\lambda)=x^2+y^2-\lambda(5x^2+8xy+5y²-9)$.
$$\begin{cases}
2x=\lambda(10x+8y)\\
2y=\lambda(8x+10y)
\end{cases}
\implies\frac{2x}{10x+8y}=\frac{2y}{8x+10y}\implies x^2=y^2.
$$
Substituting $y=\pm x$ into the ellipse equation one obtains:
$$\begin{cases}
y=x:&2x^2=1;\\
y=-x:&2x^2=9,
\end{cases}
$$
which amounts to $a=3, b=1$ as claimed.